# Use .gradle and .m2 folder in another system

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I am planning to move all my Gradle and maven projects from windows to Linux. Can I copy the .m2  and .gradle folder from windows and paste that to the proper directory in the Linux system? I just want to know that will there be any problem in running those projects in linux system after manually copying .m2 and .gradle folder?

Comment: Why don't you try this?

Comment: Why do you like to copy all that stuff? Why not building your project on the new machine which will download all the necessary parts... ?...